# How to replace new product with already added product in cart in Magento

Tags: magento

On my magento site there is check like I can only add one product in cart.If in case i am selecting other product then it should be placed in cart and remove already added item from cart.
I am thinking to do it by replacing checkout session by checking productid. Please let me know how can achieve this with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to delete all cart entry

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->delete();
```

or you can clear cart session

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
```

You can try this code in addAction of CartController